# Prevent delgated submit event from firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delegates, jquery-events

I have several dynamically created forms on my page, each with a jQuery submit event:

```
$('table').on('submit','form',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('hello');
  var form = $(e.target);
  if(typeof operation != 'undefined'){
operation.abort();
return;
  }
  var operation = $.ajax(
    //rest of my logic
  )l  
});


<form action="/update_cart/12" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input class="quantity_field text_field" id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" value="1">
</form>
```

The trouble is the form submit event fires once for each of the forms in the selector, and starts the ajax which is overloading the server. How can I make it so only the form I click fires the ajax?

Comment: target the form by id???????? or rather by context.

Comment: they are dynamically created, so not sure how I would target them to be more specific.

Comment: I’m not sure the code above is relevant. How are you triggering submit? Are you using one submit button for each form?

Comment: Can you paste the generated form HTML as well?

Comment: You dont need to be doing 'e.target', this is dealt with by the framework.

Comment: I am using the enter key, no submit button.

Comment: Added an example of the generated forms